# How to use anonymous functions in ES6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am new to front-end development and JavaScript, I am going through JavaScript ES6 classes, anonymous functions and function declarations.
I am trying to use the concept of anonymous functions in an ES6 class but I am going wrong syntactically.

I tried in following way which did not work:

```
class ChatController {
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
        this.a ++;
        console.log("hello world");
    }
   var getChat = function() {
       console.log(this.a);
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Is it possible to use anonymous functions in ES6 classes?*

Comment: No, it's not possible (unless you put them inside the constructor). Why are you trying to do that? A class contains only method definitions.

Comment: i am migrating a widget code from dojo js , and there all the functions are anonymous and the frame work supported it, here instead of widget in dojo i'm trying to using  javascript class and  it is not allowing me to use anonymous functions, if i write regular functions every thing will go to global scope and i don't want that, so i am trying to use anonymous functions

Comment: @Satyaaditya There is not much difference in scope of anonymous and named function. Second, your `getChat` is not part of class. Using `this.a` will now work. Instead, try `public get getChat() { return this.a }` and put it inside class

Comment: @Satyaaditya Please check the following **[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gbwqLh7p/3/)**. It might help you.

Comment: @Satyaaditya Please post your original code and your attempt at converting it to ES6. There's not much we can tell from this toy example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **shouldn't** add anonymous functions to your JavaScript classes, **instead declare your functions/methods in the body of the class**.

*...however*

---

### Note

**The examples below are presented here for the sake of possibility, not for recommendation!** Some of the examples below, when assigning anonymous functions **to the class/prototype**, instead of declaring them in the body of the class, are **considered bad practices for a reason. Only use them if you have a solid reason to do so!**

```js
class ChatController {
    static staticNamedFunction() {
      console.log('ChatController.staticNamedFunction()');
    }
    
    constructor(a) {
        this._a = a;
        this._a++;
        
        // ** bad practice **
        // add an anonymous function under a name 
        // to the instance of the class during construction
        this.functionFromConstructor = () => {
          console.log('ChatController.functionFromConstructor(...)');
        };
        
        console.log('ChatController.constructor(...)');
    }
    
    // regular getter
    get a() {
      return this._a;
    }
    
    // Java-style getter
    getA() {
      return this._a;
    }
    
    namedFunction() {
      console.log('ChatController.namedFunction()');
    }
}

// call a static function of the class
ChatController.staticNamedFunction();

// ** bad practice **
// add an anonymus function, that behaves as a statis function under a name
ChatController['newStaticFunction'] = () => {
  console.log('newStaticFunction');
};

// ...and call that function
ChatController.newStaticFunction();

// initialize the class to use the instance functions (or methods)
var chat = new ChatController(0);

// call a function of the class
chat.namedFunction();

// call that function, that was defined in the constructor
chat.functionFromConstructor();

// ** bad practice **
// add an anonymus function to the instance under a name
// that will only be available in this instance of the class
chat['newFunction'] = () => {
  console.log('newFunction');
}

// ..and call that function
chat.newFunction();

// ** bad practice **
// add an anonymus function to prototype of the class under a name
// that will be available on all instances of the class
// even on the previously instantiated ones
ChatController.prototype.anotherNewFunction = () => {
  console.log('anotherNewFunction');
}

// ..and call that function on the instance, that was previously declared
chat.anotherNewFunction();

// based on your sample code:
var getChat = function() {
  var chat = new ChatController(0);
  
  // accessing '_a' via a getter
  console.log(chat.a);
  
  // accessing '_a' via a Java-style getter
  console.log(chat.getA());
  
  // ** bad practice **
  // accessing '_a' directly
  console.log(chat._a);
  
  // ** bad practice **
  // adding and binding an anonymous function under a name
  chat['bindedFunction'] = function() {
    // after binding the anonymous function, you can access 
    // the instance functions/methods and variables/properties of the class
    console.log('bindedFunction', this.a);
  }.bind(chat);
  
  // ...and call that function
  chat.bindedFunction();
  
  return chat;
}

getChat(); // returns a ChatConsroller instance
```

Comment: thanks @RichardSzakacs for a detailed explanation , can you please update why it is  bad practice ,especially this one "ChatController.prototype.anotherNewFunction  = () => { "

Comment: You're welcome. It's a bad practice, because in ES6, you should rarely attach anything to the `.prototype` of an object/function/class. Just declare your methods in the body of a class. If you compile/transpile the ES6 code to ES5, the instance methods of the class will be converted to just functions on the class (function) prototype automatically anyway. **Use classes and avoid attaching functions to the class prototype in ES6.**

Comment: So, in your case, just declare your function in the body of the class, e.g. `class ChatController { anotherNewFunction() {...} }` **and that's it.** No attaching anything to `ChatController.prototype`.

Comment: **Pleased to help you!** If you find my, or any other answers on StackOverflow useful, please, don't hesitate to upvote (if you can) and if you find an answer to your particular question satisfiable, please, accept it. ;)