# React: Unable to change value by a function in setState

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to copy a value in state objects first and second through a function in setState, but the values are being changed in the object value, but not in first or second.

```
const InitVal = ({ strValue, handleClick }) => (
   <div>
        {strValue.map((item) => (
           <button onClick={() => handleClick(item.key)}>{item.key}</button>
))}
   </div>
 );
 class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {strValue: [{ key: '7' },{ key: '8' },{ key: '9' },{ key: '4' },{ key: '5' },{ key: '6' },{ key: '1' },{ key: '2' },{ key: '3' },{ key: '0' },{key: '+'},{key: '-'} ],value: '0',auxStr: '0',first: '',second: ''};
       this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
     }

   handleClick(key) {
                const { value, auxStr, first, second } = this.state;
                const digNprd = /[0-9]/;
                if (digNprd.test(key)) {
                    this.setState({ value: `${value}${key}`, auxStr: `${auxStr}${key}`} );
                } else if (key === '+') {
                    this.setState({ value: ` ${auxStr}  on  `, function(auxStr) { return { first: `${auxStr}`} } })
             
                } else if (key === '-') {
                  this.setState({ value: ` ${auxStr}  off  `, function()  { return { second: `${auxStr}`} } })
                }
            }
  render() {
    return (
      <div><br /><InitVal strValue={this.state.strValue} handleClick={this.handleClick} /> <br /> {" "}
                        <br />{" "}
                        <div>value: &nbsp;&nbsp;{this.state.value}</div>
                        <br />
                         <div>AuxStr: &nbsp;&nbsp;{this.state.value}</div>
                        <br />
                        <div>First: &nbsp;&nbsp;{this.state.first}</div>
                        <br />
                        <div>Second: &nbsp;&nbsp;{this.state.second}</div>
                    </div>
                );
  
    }
 }
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: why not simply use like this: `first: \`${auxStr}\``, `second: \`${auxStr}\``?

Comment: @ Stefan Zivkovic, I already used it, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add anonymous functions to your JavaScript classes, instead declare your functions/methods in the body of the class.

Take a look at this [How to use anonymous functions in ES6 class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083456/how-to-use-anonymous-functions-in-es6-class).

But if you wish to play around how to manage to set those `first` & `second` values with functions as you started in your codesandbox, you can use something like this with [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
...(function () {
      return { second: `${auxStr}` };
    })()
```

And again, you simply can do:

```
 first: `${auxStr}`, second: `${auxStr}`
```

Edit: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-mendeleev-ewtbw?file=/src/App.js:1354-1426)

Comment: I already simply used  first: `${auxStr}`, second: `${auxStr}`, but it didn't update the first or second. Also, I am using to switch the first with second. I tried to create snippet, some how it gave me an error and could not create.

Comment: I updated answer with codesandbox copy/paste from your code

Comment: @ Stefan Zivkovic, Thank you. Now it is working in the sandbox.

Comment: @ Stefan Zivkovic, Just trying to understand  the spread  operator ...this.aaaa(auxStr) , you used, it is not yet clear to me. Is it used for the function iteration?

Comment: @user6642297 it is used to equalize the deepness of `first`/`second` variables inside state object. Without `...` spread operator, and with the current implementation we would have `{first: 'value'}` inside state object - it would be object inside object, and that is not what we want as I can see from your constructor. Right?

Comment: @ Stefan Zivkovic,  I was trying to store the initial auxStr in first, then in the next else in the object second. once the second's value is displayed then store the second's value in first  and store null in second. So if first is empty then,     first: auxStr     if second is empty  then,     second: auxStr;      first = second         second = ' '.

Answer (score 1):

Try using arrow function
Like this

handleClick = (key) => { }